# Overloading the operator in functional amend

Tags: kdb

How to overload an operator in functional amend?

```
s:string (`a1`b2`c3)
b:string til 2
```

using functional amend with `,` gives

```
q)@[s;0 2;,;b]
("a10";"b2";"c31")
```

I want to overload the `,` (append) to prefix the content of list `b` to list `a` like :

```
("0a1";"b2";"1c3")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a custom function `{y,x}` instead if `,` to achieve this

```
@[s;0 2;{y,x};b]
("0a1";"b2";"1c3")
```

Please note that here `,` is a dyadic function; Any other dyadic function e.g. `{y,x}` can be used in functional amend with valance 4.

The general format of [functional amend](https://code.kx.com/wiki/JB:QforMortals2/functions#Functional_Forms_of_Amend) is following, where `f` is dyadic function

```
 @[L;I;f;y]

q)@[1 2 3 4 ;1 3;*;5 ]   // * is dyadic function {x*y} 
1j, 10j, 3j, 20j
```

and when `f` is monadic function

```
 @[L;I;f]

q)@[1 2 3 4 ;1 3;neg ]
1j, -2j, 3j, -4j
```